# Does Monastery weapons feat apply to the powerful fist ability?

Tags: feats, class-feature, pathfinder-2e

Monks can gain the monastery weapons feat.

> it says: "You can use melee monk weapons with any of your monk feats
>   or monk abilities that normally require unarmed attacks, though not if
>   the feat or ability requires you to use a single specific type of
>   attack, such as Crane Stance"

and the powerful fist class ability has:

> "You know how to wield your fists as deadly weapons. The damage die
>   for your fist changes to 1d6 instead of 1d4."

Now the question is: Does the feat apply also to this ability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Powerful Fists conveys no benefit to Monastery Weapons.

Monastery Weapons clarifies that it does not apply if a specific attack is called out.

> You can use melee monk weapons with any of your monk feats or monk abilities that normally require unarmed attacks, though **not if the feat or ability requires you to use a single specific type of attack**, such as Crane Stance

Powerful Fists does not alter your unarmed strikes' damage. It changes the damage of the *fists* (non-)weapon (game-term is Strike) that has the unarmed Trait.

> You know how to wield your fists as deadly weapons. The damage die **for your fist** changes to 1d6 instead of 1d4.

The "fist" is a "single specific type of attack". No other Strike will gain the damage change from d4 to d6.

Answer (score 1):

[Monastic Weaponry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=434) only applies to feats and class abilities that specifically require the monk to make one or more unarmed attacks to use them. Examples of these are [Flurry of blows](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=9), [ki Strike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=486) or [Flying kick](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=445).

Feats that interact with Monastic Weaponry but do not fall in this category, like [Brawling Focus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=438), should include the details of that interaction in their text.